# Why mysql insert ignore increase autoincrement field?

Tags: mysql

have this simple table:

```
id - key auto_increment int, 
mail - primary_key - varchar ,
type - primary_key - int,
```

Have query like: insert ignore into table (id, mail , type )...

When adding records that have the same mail and type this record is not added, this is ok.
But in the same time id field is auto increment even if no record is added.
Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Can you help me understand why `ID` is **not** your PK and `mail, type` are a UK?

Comment: That's normal behavior. auto_increment values must be generated at the time an insert is ATTEMPTED. If the insert fails, that new auto_increment value is thrown away and never re-used.

Comment: as I want mail and type to be unique for the table not id. but i still need it for some reason in the table

Comment: ok, so the only way to not to have gaps in id field, in my case, is to remove autoincrement key from it and add values to this field like id = id+1?

Comment: @abiku: make `id` your primary key, then put a unique key on the `mail,type` tuple. You can have multiple keys in the table. You're trying to subvert what a primary key is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the configuration variable `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0` to change the way InnoDB discards id's if the insert fails.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-configurable.html

> - innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0 (“traditional” lock mode)
>
>   This lock mode provides the same behavior as before innodb_autoinc_lock_mode existed. For all “INSERT-like” statements, a special table-level AUTO-INC lock is obtained and held to the end of the statement. **This assures that the auto-increment values assigned by any given statement are consecutive.**

(emphasis mine)

Note that this lock mode also has the effect of holding a table lock until the INSERT completes (either by success of failure), and that can hinder throughput if you have many concurrent threads inserting rows to the same table.

This won't necessarily have any real impact on your application, if you have a more modest rate of concurrent inserts.

So to answer your original question, the auto-inc value increases even when the insert fails in default InnoDB behavior, because that allows MySQL to release the table-lock more promptly, i.e. right after it has incremnted the auto-inc, but before it has attempted the insert.  But this means if the insert fails, some other thread may have allocated the *next* auto-inc value, so your thread can't un-allocate its id.